# php windows server 2012 how to show loaded extension

Tags: php, xampp, windows-server-2012, windows-server

On mac os, i would do this:

```
php -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());"
```

on the terminal to get the loaded extensions

but in windows server 2012, i am getting error that php is not recognised

what should i do to get the loaded extension on windows server 2012?

i am on xampp

Comment: First person I see using windows server to run PHP.

Comment: create a file with `phpinfo()`? for terminal works in windows you need create environment variable with php path and add it on windows `path`.

Comment: @AndreFerraz - You'd be surprised. There are even PHP extensions that are only available on Windows ;-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file in htdocs folder with this content, then access it by browser

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
```

or

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => bcmath
    [2] => calendar
    [3] => ctype
    [4] => date
    [5] => ereg
    [6] => filter
    [7] => ftp
    [8] => hash
    [9] => iconv
    [10] => json
    [11] => mcrypt
    [12] => SPL
    ...
)
```

**Accessing by command line**

At keyboard press <kbd>winkey</kbd> + <kbd>break/pause</kbd>, go on advanced settings, then create a new environment variable with name `PHP_HOME` value must be the php path, after this edit the variable `path`, put the cursor at end and add `;%PHP_HOME%;` confirm all operations, open a new cmd, try `php -v`

Comment: No idea about Xampp but you don't necessarily need to have the same settings (including extensions) in command line and web server.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure is exactly the same in all supported platforms. You are probably getting this error message:

> 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

This is not related to PHP. You get this message whenever you type a command that doesn't exist or cannot be found.

You can either:

- Add the PHP directory to `PATH` environment variable (just like in Unix and —I guess— MacOS)
- Switch to PHP directory first:

  ```
  cd "C:\Path\To\PHP"
  php -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());"
  ```
- Type the full path:

  ```
  "C:\Path\To\PHP\php" -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());"
  ```